# 極座標的に記録されたデータの配列をカラーマップで表示する方法

Tags: python, matplotlib

角度と半径の座標の2次元配列になった物理量をカラーマップで表示するのが目的です。
現状、次のようなコードでデータを極座標からx、y座標に変換し出力することはできています。

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import sys
from dac_read import dac_read
t=100
dac_name='./data/0???_rank=*.dac'
data1, r, theta, z = dac_read(dac_name,dimension=3)
#元からあるデータを読み取り、座標の配列r, theta, zと物理量の配列dataを作成
theta_matrix, radius_matrix = np.meshgrid(theta,r)
x = radius_matrix * np.cos(theta_matrix)
y = radius_matrix * np.sin(theta_matrix)
#x,y座標に変換
z_grid=500
plt.pcolormesh(x[z_grid,:,:],y[z_grid,:,:],data1[t,z_grid,:,:])
plt.axes().set_aspect('equal')
pp=plt.colorbar (orientation="vertical") 
pp.set_label(str(br), fontname="Arial", fontsize=24)
plt.show()
```

ここで問題がありまして、出力結果が以下の様になり、337.5~360度の部分が表示されません。
どうすれば表示できるでしょうか。

**出力結果**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1):

データが 337.5度までしかないからです。最後の部分を塗るには、先頭のデータを末尾に追加してやる必要があります。

以下の `### x, y, data1 を拡張` 〜 `###` の部分を参考にしてください。

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import sys

# サンプルデータを作成

theta = [ 2 * np.pi * i / 16 for i in range(16) ]
r = [ r for r in range(10) ]
theta_matrix, radius_matrix = np.meshgrid(theta, r)

x = radius_matrix * np.cos(theta_matrix)
y = radius_matrix * np.sin(theta_matrix)

data1 = np.array([
    [
        row for col in range(16)
    ]
    for row in range(10)
], dtype=np.float32)

### x, y, data1 を拡張

x = np.append(x, x[:, 0:1], axis=1)
y = np.append(y, y[:, 0:1], axis=1)
data1 = np.append(data1, data1[:, 0:1], axis=1)

###

plt.pcolormesh(x[:,:],y[:,:],data1[:,:])
plt.axes().set_aspect('equal')
pp=plt.colorbar (orientation="vertical") 
pp.set_label('noname', fontname="Arial", fontsize=24)
plt.show()
```

[image: 描画結果]